# Получить данные о таблице в Hibernate. Проблема в таймере (shedule)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

Есть файлы:
 - `UserRepository.java`
 - `UserService.java`
 - `Thread.java`
 - `Task.java`

При запуске программы выводится ошибка каждую минуту (логично), что в классе `Task` в строчке `List<User> users = userServices.findAllUsers();` у меня ничего не "принимается", т.е. Hibernate не желает выполнять мой запрос. Ошибка типичная - `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Вопрос: почему Hibernate не хочет брать данные с таблицы `users` и выводить данные в потоке, хотя при обычной загрузке страницы (в методе, @getmapping) `findAllUsers()` срабатывает?

Вот мои файлы:

Application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=USER
spring.datasource.password=PASS
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://LOCALHOST

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

# Hibernate DDL auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

**UserRepository.java:**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findAll();
}
```

**UserService.java:**

```
@Service
public class UserServices {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServices(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public List<User> findAllUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Threads.java:**

```
public class Threads {
    public void start() {
        Task task = new Task();
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task::downloadCalendars, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

**Task.java:**

```
public class Task {

    private Cutter cutter = new Cutter();

    @Autowired
    private UserServices userServices;

    void downloadCalendars(){
        try {
            LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
            if(time.getHour() == 0 && time.getMinute() == 0) {
                List<User> users = userServices.findAllUsers();
                for (User user : users) {
                    new Thread(() -> {
                        try {
                            cutter.updateCalendar(user);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            if (user != null) {
                                System.out.println("проблема в user " + user.getId());
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае все достаточно просто.
Хибернейт тут не причем. Ошибка NullPointerException никакого отношения к хибернейту не имеет. Возникает она потому, что вы вызываете метод у неинициализированной(Null) переменной. 
В данном случае это переменная userServices.findAllUsers().
А вот вопрос , почем эта переменная не инициализируется относится уже к понимаю работы спринга.
У спринга есть контекст. По сути вся работа спринга сводится к созданию контейнера, в котором хранятся бины (ваши репозитории, контроллеры, сервисы и т.д.)
Вместе с тем, Ваш класс Task  не является бином (на нем нет никаких аннотаций), это значит , что вы вышли за пределы контекста спринга, он не знает ничего о экземплярах класса Task , а значит не может и выполнить инициализацию вашей переменной private UserServices userServices, которая именно для этого (для автоматической инициализации спрингом) помечена аннотацией @Autowired. 
Сделайте ваш класс компонентом, создайте его также с помощью спринга (не через оператор new, иначе получите ту же проблему по той же причине) и будет вам счастье.

В вашем случае уберем `Thread.java`, т.к. он нам не понадобится и останемся работать с `Task.java`.

Добавим немного аннотаций в класс `Task.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class Task {

    private Cutter cutter = new Cutter();

    @Autowired
    private UserServices userServices;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 30 9 * * *")//например, выполняется в 9:30 каждый день
    void downloadCalendars(){
      ...
    }
```

И вот вы обрели счастье)

Comment: добавил аннотацию `@Component` вначале класса Task и не сработало. Счастья еще не обрел)

Comment: а как вы создаете экземпляр класса таск? Task task = new Task(); - если так, как показано в коде, то прочитайте еще раз ответ))

Comment: `Task task = new Task()` в Thread. Пробовал заменить на `@Autowired Task task` и, дав классам Task и Thread @component, не сработало...

Comment: ваш класс public class Threads должен быть компонентом. и тогда вопрос в том, каким образом создается экземпляр этого класса? а вообще у спринга есть аннотация @Scheduled , а в ней крон. ставится над методом, который нужно выполнить по расписанию...

Comment: Да, я прочитал пару ресурсов уже про @Schedule. Сейчас модерация, надеюсь, подтвердит поправки в вашем ответе и тогда будет галка) В любом случае будет, ибо ответ помог!

Comment: Если не получится - пишите, не стесняйтесь. Ну и желательно напишите, если код заработает) Удачи

Comment: Код сработал) Даже Thread-класс не понадобился. P.S. в спринге новичок, поэтому "туплю"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91172/discussion-between-antonio112009-and--).